# Bootstrap 3 - How to keep the Nav Collapse Component Open onLoad

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Bootstrap3 and using a collapsible element to in my design.

```
<!-- Search Filter -->
<div id="search-filter">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-5 col-xs-12">

        <!-- Collapse Search -->
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle navbar-toggle-search-filter" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#searchbar-collapse-set"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span> </button>
        <!-- /Collapse Search -->

        <h3>Showing 345 Results <small>(Hill Stations around Bangalore)</small></h3>

      </div>

      <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="searchbar-collapse-set">

        <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">
          <div class="distance">
            <h5>distance:</h5>
            <div id="distance-slider"></div>
            <span class="distance-value">250 kms</span>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12">
          <div class="sort">
            <h5>sort:</h5>
            <ul class="nav nav-pills">
              <li class="active"><a href="#">popular</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">name</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">distance</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
      <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->

      <div class="clearfix"></div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- /Search Filter -->
```

How can i use Media-Query or JS to keep it opened on smaller devices by default?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the "in" class to your searchbar-collapse-set div like so:

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse in" id="searchbar-collapse-set">
```

**EDIT:**

The toggle is controlled by a media query.  It's display is set to none at 768px in this rule:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-toggle {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

So you can either override the rule in your own styles or customize the Bootstrap css file.

Comment: is there a way i can activate it using JS. i want to toggle the icon for the button as well

Comment: The point at which the toggle is displayed is set in the css.  It's not controlled by the js.  Yes, you could write a js/jQuery function to control displaying or hiding the toggle, but then you'd have to check the window width and deal with resize events.  Honestly, it's easier to use css for this.  Also, you don't have to use the navbar-collapse class.  You can set any div to be a collapsable element, then you don't have to override the existing navbar-toggle rules, just create your own.

Comment: i want the collapse class so that it works in sync with the breakpoints and i dont have to be bothered about managing them :D